# Finding The location of items in a number array inside a string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am working on a Chat bot for discord that has an addition calculator.... I am currently trying to find the .indexOf the first time a number appears in the string... For ex: !add 1 + 1 would be the command to add 1 and 1... I have an array that I use that contains all single numbers ex:

```
const singleNumbers = [
0,
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
];
```

when I get the string back I am using

```
for (const num of singleNumbers){
const num1 = msg.content.indexOf(num,);
const add = '+';
const locationOfAdd = msg.content.indexOf(add,);
const num2 = msg.content.indexOf(num,locationOfAdd);
const add1 = msg.content.slice(num1,) * 1;
const add2 = msg.content.slice(num2,) * 1;
msg.reply(add1 + add2);
}
```

When I run this... It for some reason will only use the first number of the Array so the numbers I use in !add 1 + 1 have to start with 0... so !add 01 + 01 which in math is fine... but for simplicity how do I make it be able to start with any number in the array rather than the first... If you don't know discord.js,

```
msg.content
```

Is the string returned so if I type in chat...
Hey Guys what's goin on? 
it would return as a String ("Hey Guys what's goin on?")... 
To sum this all up... I am wondering how to make my const num that I declared in my for of loop check for all the numbers in its array rather than just the first in my case 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to find the index for the first digit `str.search(/[0-9]/)` or `str.match/[0-9]/).index`.

Using [regex](https://regex101.com/r/fjrrK4/1) to extract the numbers, and reduce to add them:

match on: string starts with !add, at least one space, at least one digit as a capture group, optional space and a + sign, another series of digits as a capture group.
You get an array with [full match, digit group 1, digit group 2].  I slice off the full match, and then use reduce to (+x converts the string to a number; you could also use Number(x)) to add each number and collect it in sum.

```
const sum = msg.content.match(/^!add\s+(\d+)\s*\+\s*(\d+)/).slice(1).reduce((sum,x)=>+x+sum,0)
```

Note: \d is the same as [0-9]

[JavaScript.info RegExp tutorial](https://javascript.info/regexp-methods)

Comment: Thank You... I will look into this, I am newer to the Javascript field along with its libraries so this will take a little bit to learn but I will look into it... Thank you for the Information!!!

Comment: If you want to do it with indexOf and an array of matches, you will have to loop through all the elements in the array and use indexOf for each one, or loop through all the characters and search the array for your match

Comment: How exactly would I loop through each individual one?

Comment: `for (const char of [...str]) doStuffWithCharacter(char)` uses the spread operator to iterate on chars

Comment: had I not already done that in my example using the for of loop?

Comment: This is to iterate on the characters of the string, not your array.  Also I recommend learning RegEx, and then later some kind of grammar parsing if Discord doesn't have something already built-in.  It will make it much easier to parse Discord commands and perhaps do something complicated later

Comment: Ohh, That makes sense... I am going to look into some syntax for that

Comment: Also its not discord in specific... I am using node.js as a module host and discord.js as the library extension

Comment: Which is both a string and array method... so do I use the string method?

Comment: split only works on strings.  it "splits" the string on every match it finds and returns an array.  So as an example. "!add 1 + 1", you could do `const [command, digit1, , digit2] = "!add 1 + 1".split(' '); if(command==='!add') console.log(+digit1 + +digit2)`

Comment: Im sorry your right I was thinking of splice or slice... I have to re look at the documentation... Thank you for your help... After I look into this I will be sure to mark you as the answer... its currently 2am where I'm at so It will be a little before I can look over this (about 12 hrs)